# How to display text on a cursor

Tags: javascript

I've seen this in some website but I can't find how to do it (like idk if I need a framework or something to do it).

The example:
https://gyazo.com/0dac992b134a51f9c4d4f9146e3c82d2

there is an alternative example where the cursor is transformed :https://gyazo.com/5c6ffdbed389384a91adaaf225cfbb2e

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***>>>[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+animated+cursor+follow+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for tooltips if I understood it correctly.
"CSS Tooltip" https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp
Here is article from w3schools on how to do it with bare css.
Customizing cursor in html:
"Changing the Cursor with CSS for Better User Experience (or Fun) | CSS-Tricks" https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/